# How to combine a number in a string separated by a space instead of comma?

Tags: python, text-parsing

```
text = "Among a total of 56 336 patients with valvular AF"
```

I'm using the following regex to pull the number, but since there isn't a comma between the 56 and 336, only 56 is picked up as the population.

```
allvalues = re.findall(r'([–.%\d]+)', text)
population = allvalues[0]
print("Population is ",population)
```

How can I modify this code so that it also accounts for this scenario where the number is separated by a space, not comma? I'm looking for a solution that will resolve this but also keep working on texts that have the number without comma ie 56336 and with comma ie 56,336.

Comment: i dont think your code would match 56,366 either at the moment... it would however match 56-366 ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley you're right! updated it so it works with the comma: allvalues = re.findall(r'([–,.%\d]+)', text)

Answer (score 3):

Just allow for matching a number followed by an optional space and another number:

```py
text = "Among a total of 56 336 patients with valvular AF also 1,234"
allvalues = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?:[ ,]?\d{3})*', text)
print(allvalues)  # ['56 336', '1,234']
```

Comment: That works for the space, but then it doesn't work for 56,336. Anyway to add that in to your regex?

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: nice edit :) thats great +1 ( i think it still misses his 56336 case though)

Comment: @Joran It's not what you think...the initial OP did not make it clear that the space is a thousands separator, hence my answer did not bother to enforce this.

Answer (score 1):

you need a more thorough regex...

```
import re
target_string = "Among a total of 56 336 patients with valvular AF"
allvalues = re.findall(r""" # regex to match numbers
               [+-] ?  # optionally a + or a - at the start
               \d +  # followed by one or more integer digits
               (?: # a non capturing group
                 [, ] ? # optionally followed by a space or a comma
                 \d{3}  # follwed by 3 integers
               ) * # this whole group is optional or can repeate
               % ? # optionally it has a percent symbol at the end
             """, target_string, re.VERBOSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for one number in the string:

```
import re
txt = "Among a total of 56 336 patients with valvular AF"
l = [s for s in txt.split() if s.isdigit()]
population = int(''.join(l)) 
print("Population is ",population)
```